# How to add a document type to a new XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, doctype

How do I add the following document type to the begining of an XML file

```
<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">
```

I am trying to create an XML file using C# `XDocument` but cant figure out how to add the above to the beginning of the xml file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an [`XDocumentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299381.aspx) to the beginning of the `XDocument`:

```
var xDocument = new XDocument(
  new XDocumentType(
    "smil",
    "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN",
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd",
    null
  ),
  new XElement("Root")
);
```

Comment: How do you accept an answer in stackoverflow. I keep getting these warnings about not accepting answers.

Comment: @user1204195: You click the hollow checkmark at the left beneath the number.

Comment: @user1204195: You click the check mark to the left of the answer below the vote counter.

Comment: @user1204195: Now, I'm not fishing for votes, but if you like an answer (or a question) you can click the up arrow to the left. Likewise, if you dislike something you can click the down arrow (and perhaps add a comment explaining why). Perhaps you should read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `XmlDocument.CreateDocumentType()`?
[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createdocumenttype.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createdocumenttype

```
//Create the XmlDocument.
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

//Create a document type node and  
//add it to the document.
XmlDocumentType doctype;
doctype = doc.CreateDocumentType("book", null, null, "<!ELEMENT book ANY>");
doc.AppendChild(doctype);

//Create the root element and 
//add it to the document.
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("book"));
```